# Drawing segments over the background of a flot plot

Tags: javascript, flot

I want to draw 2 segments over a flot plot (I have 4 x-coordinates to determine those: x1, x2, x3 and x4). Much like:

[image]

But then with a continuing plot line over the colored areas. I found this image from [this blogpost](http://joeloughton.com/blog/web-applications/flot-plugins-x-gap-threshold/), and I have looked at the code, but I can't seem to figure out how to transfer the colored areas.

I think I need to use this command from the [git code](https://github.com/oughton/flot-plugin-collection/blob/master/src/flot/jquery.flot.xgap.js):

```
ctx.fillRect(x1 + offset.left, offset.top, x2 - x1, plotHeight - offset.bottom - offset.top);
```

But I can't seem to figure out what ctx is. I have a flot graph:

```
tensionPlot = new CustomPlot(placeholder,  [ { data: dataD}, { data: dataM}, { data: dataK}, {label:"first data", data:dataK}, {label:"Second data", data:dataM},{label:"Third data", data:dataD} ]
, options, dataSync);
```

But is ctx part of the options? Or is that an additional new canvas? I haven't figured out where to fit this in.

http://joeloughton.com/blog/web-applications/flot-plugins-x-gap-threshold/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that directly in Flot by using markings (see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) in the documentation). Example code (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yv64gLga/) for a full example):

```
markings: [
    { xaxis: { from: 150, to: 200 }, color: "#ff8888" },
    { xaxis: { from: 500, to: 750 }, color: "#ff8888" }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to do it dynamically, but so far no luck. I think I have  slightly wrong command:     this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.axis.from = 50;
    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.axis.to = 500;
    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.color = "#ff8888";
    this.plot.setupGrid();
    this.plot.draw();

Comment: `xaxis`, not `axis`